# How do I display an html file on a web browser in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, apache2, mysql, openstack, html

I am tasked with displaying a program on a web browser for my final project. The browser would be run from a cloud instance, and I have chosen to show an java applet that I have made. I have already install apache2, mysql, and php on the instance. How do I actually make the html file work on the instance, so that a user can go to the url and see the java applet?

I am very new to ubuntu and linux in general, so a simple explanation would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already written the HTML file, you simple must move it to /var/www/. There is already an index.html file there, you can overwrite it (it's pretty boring). Then, you can see your web page by going to `http://localhost/` in your browser. If your page is written in PHP (which it seems you may have hinted at), move it to /var/www/ and delete /var/www/index.html. The rest is the same - Apache will render the PHP for you and you can still find it at `localhost`.

Comment: Great answer, could you tell us how to move it there as drag and drop is not allowed and editing is prohibited as it belongs to host?

Comment: I ran my editing software as `sudo geany` and it allowed me to save to the folder, but I'm scratching around Terminal now looking for the delete command!

Comment: Well, there's two way - both of which involve a terminal. If you like moving files with Ubuntu's file manager, Nautilus, simply run 'gksudo nautilus'. Then you can drag and drop your file as you will have full administrative permissions.

The second way is 'sudo mv /path/to/file/index.html /var/www/'

EDIT: The delete command is rm

Comment: Thank you, I just found `sudo unlink file_name.ext` which works as well.

Comment: Localhost doesn't work, but using my local IP does work. How do I display this web page online then?

Comment: Fedders - That may warrant a whole new question. The gist is: You must set up port forwarding on your network to your server. If it is connected directly to a modem, you must set the modem to forward requests on port 80 to your server. If your server is connected to a router which is then connected to the modem, you must configure both to forward requests. Router and modem configuration can typically be modified by visiting their local IPs in a browser, once you find them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just right-clicking it and choosing the browser you want to open it in :

[image]